# Angular2 - Detect an empty number being supplied

Tags: javascript, angular

I get a number in an input text field. When I press a button, that value is echoed back to me with `console.log(...)`. There is a function that is being called on (click), its prototype is something like this: `myFunc(value : number)`.

To make sure I get a number, I am using `Number(value)`. The problem is, when the value received is empty (the text field is empty), this return 0.

How can I detect if value is empty ? == null or === null do not work, and comparing with `''` or `""` gives an error as those operator cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string'.

The ideal result would be to get NaN if the value is anything but a number.

Comment: just if (x) { ... }

Comment: @Avihaym if the value is 0, then it will return false, despite not being empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if(value + "" == "" && other check... ) {
```

Comment: Property 'to_string' does not exist on type 'number'.

Comment: @user96649 you're welcome. It's not the cleanest way but it works

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `typeof(value)` return `string` if there is no number supplied, which can then be used in a condition. This would solve my issue and let me identify empty values.

Comment: If anyone got a better way, I'm willing to accept his answer.